# VB.NET: Adding Textbox to Drag and Drop Handler

Tags: vb.net

So I'm new here and newish to programming (I did a paper 6 years ago in vb.net).
I'm trying to write a program for work where basically I drag and drop a photo from an explorer window into a textbox, which then displays the file path, and then the user clicks a button and it renames all of the files in the textbox and puts it in a specified folder.

[Picture of the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2sXts.png)

The problem I'm having is with a feature which allows me to add another textbox, by clicking the "+" button, and having this textbox able to have the file drag and dropped into it. What I have at the moment is below. As far as my research tells me, this should pretty much work.

```
    Private Sub btnAddS01_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddS01.Click

    Dim addTB As New TextBox
    Dim addLBL As New Label

    lblNumberS1 = lblNumberS1 + 1

    With addTB
        .Name = "txtS0100" + lblNumberS1.ToString
        .Location = New Point(113, TBx1)
        .Size = New Size(499, 20)
        .AllowDrop = True
        AddHandler addTB.DragDrop, AddressOf Me.tb_DragEnter
        AddHandler addTB.DragDrop, AddressOf Me.tb_DragDrop
    End With
    Panel0.Controls.Add(addTB)

    With addLBL
        .Name = "lbltxtS0100" + lblNumberS1.ToString
        .Text = "00" + lblNumberS1.ToString
        .Location = New Point(71, LBLx1)
        .Font = New Font(addLBL.Font, FontStyle.Bold)
    End With
    Panel0.Controls.Add(addLBL)

    End Sub
```

Note: lblNumberS1 is a global variable, that allows me to keep count of each section and add the correct label number no matter what order the user clicks the "+" button.

Now it goes to the drag and drop/drag enter subs.
Please don't flame me for all of the hardcoded textboxes, I couldn't find a better way, but if you know of an easier way, I'm open to it!

```
Public Sub tb_DragEnter(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs) Handles txtH01.DragEnter, txtH02.DragEnter,
    S01_001.DragEnter, S02_001.DragEnter, S03_001.DragEnter, S04_001.DragEnter, S05_001.DragEnter, S06_001.DragEnter,
    S07_001.DragEnter, S08_001.DragEnter, S09_001.DragEnter

    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy

End Sub


Public Sub tb_DragDrop(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs) Handles txtH01.DragDrop, txtH02.DragDrop,
    S01_001.DragDrop, S02_001.DragDrop, S03_001.DragDrop, S04_001.DragDrop, S05_001.DragDrop, S06_001.DragDrop,
    S07_001.DragDrop, S08_001.DragDrop, S09_001.DragDrop

    Dim files() As String = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop)
    For Each path In files

        If e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop) Then
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy
            sender.AppendText(path)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Hopefully that all makes sense.

Any help/constructive criticism would be appreciated!
:)